# Help identifying this snake maze board game

Tags: identify-this-game

Here is a short video showcasing a two-player table-top game produced by the Mexican toy company Lily-Ledy (most of its games were licensed from worldwide toy vendors, re-branded and manufactured in Mexico). The play mechanics are a bit similar to the old Aardvark computer game.

Can anyone identify if [this game](https://youtu.be/AK6fiwVcPIU) exists under a different toy brand?

Here are some pictures of the game, (sorry for the grainy quality)
[image]

[image]
**Game description:**

- The objective of the game is to efficiently maneuver a snake around a
  labyrinth, while trying to grab more pellets than your opponent.
- Each opponent controls a protruding snake with two knobs.
- One knob controls how much the serpent protrudes or retracts, while the other knob changes the snake's direction.
- The tip of the snake is magnetic
  so it will attract the pellets.

Comment: Link-only questions are likely to be closed. Please add a description of the game to your question so the question will still stand when the video is no longer reachable (and so the words in the description can provide a better set of search term hits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This game was manufactured in Canada and sold (© 1983) by the U.S. toy company Parker Brothers under the name [Sidewinder](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5626/sidewinder). A sidewinder is a type of rattlesnake that is known for its side-to-side wiggling form of locomotion, which is similar to the motion of the game pieces.

Instructions, box, game (click to enlarge):

[image: Instructions, box, game]

(Image source: a sold-out Etsy listing for the game ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20230828154007/https://www.etsy.com/ca/listing/1425197609/1983-sidewinder-game-by-parker-brothers?show_sold_out_detail=1&ref=nla_listing_details)).)

Description from BoardGameGeek:

> A closed board houses a number of 'hidden' locations, each of which contains a small steel marble.
>
> Players manipulate their plastic 'sidewinder' snake, tipped with a magnet, to find the hidden balls and retrieve them for points. It's a lot harder than it looks. Care must be taken when some of the locations force you to twist your 'snake' in almost impossible shapes.

The Mexican version, branded by Lili-Ledy, was called Laberinto, or labyrinth/maze. The Mexican version also depicts snakes on the box.

In August 2023 there was a copy of the Laberinto game for sale on a Mexican website ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20230825193717/https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-1769615454-juego-antiguo-laberinto-de-lili-ledy-en-caja-_JM)) with several pictures, including the box and the game itself, which matches the image in the question.

Comment: Excellent answer  =)